# How to not create a collection for base model with Mongoose Discriminators?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

In the documentation of [Mongoose discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html), it shows Event and ClickedLinkEvent sample models for discriminators:

```
const options = { discriminatorKey: 'kind' };

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ time: Date }, options);
const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

const ClickedLinkEvent = Event.discriminator('ClickedLink',
  new mongoose.Schema({ url: String }, options));
```

I applied this to my models, but it creates collection for Event, not ClickedLinkEvent. I want ClickedLinkEvent to inherit all fields and create collection for this model, not for Event.

Is there any way to inherit fields from Event, but not create a collection for it? Or should I make it with discriminators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrimination column concept implies the single table(RDBMS) or collection(MongoDB) storage for different entities.

The use case is to simplify operation on common fields of similar object. E.g. search/count all events (including clicking) by date in the given example.

Don't use discriminators if you need separate collections. Use "inheritance" on schema definition level, it will be limited to javascript space. For the click event example:

```
// common fields
const eventDefinition = { time: Date }
// specific fields
const ClickedLinkEventDefinition = {...eventDefinition, url: String}

// completely separate models and collections on db level
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema(eventDefinition, options);
const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

const ClickedLinkEvent = new mongoose.Schema(ClickedLinkEventDefinition , options);
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Alex Blex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618825/284199) is right. But as I understood we can still use the discrimators with the schemas. Here was my solution:

```
const options = { discriminatorKey: 'kind' };

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ time: Date }, options);

const ClickedLinkEventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ field: { type: Number } }, options);
const ClickedLinkEventBase = mongoose.model('ClickedLink', ClickedLinkEventSchema)

const ClickedLinkEvent = ClickedLinkEventBase.discriminator('Event', eventSchema);
```